# load images in tableview ios6.1

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimageview, uitableview

How do I load images in uitableview ios6.1 .

I am currently using  **SDWebImage** https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage and it works .But sometimes it does not load the image .

Is there any other library better than the one I am using ? I am a beginner in ios and it would help me a great deal.

Thanks in Advance.

This is the code I am using for now :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code, and SDWebImage is actually one of the more/most popular libraries. You can try AFNetworking if you don't care about caching.  What exactly do you mean by 'it does not load the image'? You just see the placeholder all the time?

Comment: Yes I do see that but I loaded the itunes json feed for 50 images and 3 of them did not load at all .I had to exit/close the app and start the app again to see it load.

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback Sir .SO SDWebImage is currently the best ? and I can go ahead with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm putting this in an answer because it was too long for a comment:

SDWebImage package is strong for its caching - especially on-disk caching which can be a bit of a pain in iOS (with different OS versions supporting different levels/types of caching). SDWebImage also provides a lot of good functionality - you can see the main points on their GitHub page (it's the bullet list at the top).

If it's just the UIImageView category you're after (which provides the `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` method) then some (I'd like to say 'most' but I can't back it up with data/stats) people use AFNetworking since more likely than not they're already using that as their network stack. Our production app uses AFNetworking + SDWebImage because we need the extensive AFNetworking functionality but also on-disk caching.

Oh and with regards to the images not downloading - it's possible it was a network issue. The fact that you didn't get an error and the app didn't crash is pretty much the point of the functionality that SDWebImage adds. Implementing a similar method would require handling the error cases (network error vs unauthorized vs wrong URL) and also updating the UIImageView without blocking the main thread, all of which can be quite complicated to implement, not just for a beginner but also for intermediate programmers. The functionality seems simple - download an image, use a placeholder, and update when the image arrives - but it's definitely a non-trivial task.

Comment: Thanks a Ton Sir.SDWebImage worked almost perfectly in my case and I was out looking for something better or alternative(just curious).I also thought ios6.1 would have some internal methods to do so.I will continue using SDWebImage for now and Please Sir do let me know if ios6.1 is implementing any method to take care of the above requirement.Thanks again Sir Have a Great Day.

Comment: Just an addon query .If any image has not been loaded as you had mentioned ,How do I check that and reload those particular images? Is there anyway possible to do that in SDWebImage.Thanks again.

Comment: You can set progress and completion blocks for `setImageWithURL` using something like `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:options:progress:completed:` - full details can be found at http://hackemist.com/SDWebImage/doc/Categories/UIImageView(WebCache).html#//api/name/setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:options:progress:completed: but basically you can put code into the progress block to confirm why it's not downloading, and in the completion block you can check for image data and if it's not there, you can force a retry. Normally I'd just let it fail gracefully though.

Comment: I'm running SDWebImage from https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/ result in build success but didn't show in simulator IOS6.1